# getline delimiter using stringstream

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

It seems that it's not separating the word within the space.

Trying to separate the words in between, and stored it in first and second.

```
cin >> name; //input name 
stringstream file (name);
getline(file,first, ' '); //seperate the name with the first name and last name using space 
getline(file,second, ' ');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
cin >> name;
```

with

```
getline(cin, name); //input name
```

`cin >>` reads only upto the first space. You would have realized this if you done a `cout << name;` to check what's getting read - this is the first step of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

When you read the initial input with `cin >> name;` that only reads up to the first white space character.

You then try to break that into two pieces at white space, which it doesn't contain.

Easy way:

```
cin >> first >> second;
```

Alternatively, if you start with `std::getline(cin, name);` instead of `cin >> name;`, then the rest should work correctly.